# Remove Back button in SearchView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, searchview, android-appcompat

I have some problem when I try to display my **SearchView**.

What I need:

1.Make **SearchView** always opened without any close buttons.

2.Display another icon after **Searchview**

My code:

**menu_fragment_xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CardBaseFragment">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />
    <item android:id="@+id/сhange_country"
        android:title="@string/add_new_card"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionBarWidgetTheme="@style/myStyle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_change_country">

    </item>

</menu>
```

**style:**

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Gets rid of the "underline" in the text -->
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon when the SearchView is expanded -->
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <!-- The hint text that appears when the user has not typed anything -->
    <item name="queryHint">Test</item>

</style>
```

Now, when program starts , everything is ok, but still I have back button.

When I change **SearchView** `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` to `"always"` , SearchView overlap my second item, how can I remove back button correctly, without creating new layout for toolbar?

```
  ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Didn't help.

Comment: Create your own custom layout for it and don't use searchview if you don't want any functionality of it.

Comment: @VivekMishra i need searchview funtionality, and i need it to be always opened, i just want disable searchview collapse

Comment: This issue is common on Android 23 and higher https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410048/searchview-in-expanded-mode-doesnt-hide-all-action-bar-icons-starting-from-mars

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, after `setContentView` call below method to hide back button completely

```
public void HideHomeButton(){
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false); // disable the button
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // remove the left caret
     ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responce, but it didn't help

Answer (score -1):

to make SearchView always opened change: `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`
to `app:showAsAction="always"`

to display another icon after Searchview if you want it always visible choose `app:showAsAction="always"` to it

Comment: He doesn't ask about making searchview always opened (expanded). Check this question to understand his problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410048/searchview-in-expanded-mode-doesnt-hide-all-action-bar-icons-starting-from-mars

Comment: The worst answer ever